# What is the technical term for this "instantaneous dataset swap?"

Tags: terminology

Google is not catching on to what I'm trying to ask it.  Hopefully someone here will.

I'm looking for the technical term that describes this:

You have a dataset or application that is accessed by customers 24/7.  Each day you need to create a new, revised dataset (or application), and when it's done being created, it gets instantaneously swapped out with the dataset/application from the day before, with no downtime to the client.  The new, revised dataset needs to end up having the same name as the original, so the revised is usually populated or built in some kind of temporary or holding table until it's completed, at which point, the swap occurs.  What happens to the old data is irrelevant to the question, but just for example's sake, we can say it gets deleted.

I've heard this described in no more than two words before, and I don't recall what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a "hot swap." Although it's mostly used in terms of computer systems it can be used in other areas as well.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping

Comment: Since this is the term that was in my brain but I couldn't fish it out - you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called an [“atomic operation” or “atomic transaction”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Comment: Thanks Rob, while this is great info (and a great read so far!) "hot-swapping" is more along the lines of what I used to hear this called, so I'm marking Mauricio's answer.  Your answer is really great knowledge for me though. Thanks again.